# Convertir una consulta LINQ en un objeto

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework, linq

No puedo transformar esta consulta de `linq` a un objeto para poder acceder a su información directamente si tener que transformarla en un `array`.

```
var list = from PEL_T_Peliculas in dbDatos.PEL_T_Peliculas
           join PEL_T_TipoPelicula in dbDatos.PEL_T_TipoPelicula
               on PEL_T_Peliculas.idTipo equals PEL_T_TipoPelicula.IdTipo

           where country.Contains(PEL_T_Peliculas.Pais) && type.Contains(PEL_T_TipoPelicula.Tipo)
           select PEL_T_Peliculas.Titulo + ";" + PEL_T_Peliculas.Pais + ";" + PEL_T_TipoPelicula.Tipo;
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien. Te refieres a que esa consulta solo devuelve un resultado y quieres un objeto en lugar de una colección?

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que esperas recibir es un conjunto de objetos, no necesitas convertir a array, puedes hacerle un `foreach` directamente a `list` y ahí tienes cada uno de los objectos en cada paso del bucle. Otra cosa es que quieras acceder a los resultados por índice, entonces sí, necesitas hacer `.ToArray()` o `.ToList()`.

Si estás seguro de que sólo vas a obtener un resultado, puedes hacer `var item = (from ...).Single()`; o si podrías no recibir ninguno, `.SingleOrDefault()`.

Esta información puede servirte de ayuda: [Métodos de LINQ en la clase Enumerable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable).

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta. Sólo una cosa más, si quisiera mostrar esta consulta en una tabla con paginado de tres registros por página. Cómo podría realizarlo. Ha de cambiar de página a página cuando se pulse un botón de elemento input.

Comment: Para paginación puedes combinar `Skip` y `Take` (documentados en el enlace en mi respuesta) para recuperar un subconjunto de los datos disponibles.